# get Age of a person in android and tell them in which group they are

Tags: android

Hello every one i am new in android and now i want to create function that get age of a person and tell them in which group they are,  for example if the age was between 4 to 11, thay are in child group...but i have a problem that i dont know what the return should be?
thank for any help
here is my code:

```html
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.R.anim;
import android.R.bool;
import android.R.string;
import android.renderscript.Int2;

public class Human {
 //Property
 String Fname;
 String Lname;
 boolean Gender;
 Date Birthday;
 int Age;
 
 //Method
 public Human() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 

 //Get Age of a Person
  public Date GetAge (Date c ){
   
  SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  java.util.Date C = null;
  java.util.Date B = null;
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  try
  {
   c = dfDate.parse("01/1/2016");
   B =  dfDate.parse(dfDate.format(cal.getTime()));
   return B;
   
  }catch (java.text.ParseException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
   
   int difDays = (int) ((c.getTime() - B.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24));
   System.out.println(difDays);
  return B;
   
 
   
  
 }
  
  
 //Get Group of a Person
  
  public String GetGroup(int Age)
  {
   
   if (Age >= 1 &&  Age <= 10) {
    
    return ("child");
    
   
  } 
   
   else if (Age >= 11 &&  Age <= 45)  {
   
         
     return ("young");
  } 
   
   
   else if (Age >= 45 )  {
    
    return ("old");
  }
   
   
  return toString()  ;
   
     
  }
 
  
  
  
  


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i dont know what the return should be" ? Did you test parts of your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();  
dob.setTime(dateOfBirth);  
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();  
int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
  age--;  
} else if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    && today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
  age--;  
}
```